# How to Ensure a BehaviorSubject always has a value?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm writing this application in Angular and I'm using Resolvers.

Once the user loads a given page, there is an API-Endpoint that will be hit by the resolver and one of the parameters that needs to be passed is the user's country. To get that info, I'm using the **ip-api.com** API.

Here is my problem. Because I'm using Observables, I can't get the country location on time, before the request is out. I need to have the user's country first and then send the request.

My idea was to create a service that gets injected in the `root`, so as soon as the application starts its constructor executes a method to fetch the user location data. Then, I store that data on a `BehaviorSubject` so it can be accessed by any class that needs it later.

How can I ensure that I will always have the data I need before any request goes out?

If the user comes from the main page everything works well, but if the user goes directly to a secondary page, then I get an error.

Here is what I got:

### Helper Service

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable( { providedIn: 'root' } )
export class HelperService {
    public showRightDrawer = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public requestCountry = new BehaviorSubject<string>(undefined);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.detectUserLocation();
    }

    detectUserLocation(): void {
        const url = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
        this.http.get(url).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((c: any) => {
            const cc = c.countryCode;
            this.requestCountry.next(cc);
            return cc;
        });
    }
}
```

### Service that hits my internal API

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SERVER_URL } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HelperService } from '../common/services/helper.service';
import { Roaster } from './roaster.interface';

@Injectable()
export class RoasterService {
    private endPoint: string = SERVER_URL;
    private country: string;
    private httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            responseType: 'text'
        })
    };

    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private helper: HelperService) {
        helper.requestCountry.subscribe((c) => this.country = c);
    }

    getRoasters(page?: number, limit?: number): Observable<Roaster[]> {
        const reqLimit = limit || 15;
        const reqPage = page || 0;
        return this.httpService
          .get<Roaster[]>(`${this.endPoint}roaster?limit=${reqLimit}&page=${reqPage}&country=${this.country.toLowerCase()}`, this.httpOptions )
          .pipe(take(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's best not to subscribe in your services.  Observables are lazy by nature, and subscribing in the constructor of a service causes data to be fetched regardless of whether or not a consumer is subscribing to it.

You can expose your data in your HelperService as an observable without subscribing like this:

```js
export class HelperService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    private url = 'http://ip-api.com/json';

    public countryCode$ = this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
        map(response => response.countryCode),
        shareReplay()
    );
}
```

You see we use [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) to transform the response to the relevant property.  We use -[`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) so that multiple subscribers will share the same subscription and receive an already received value. Now, consumers can subscribe to `countryCode$` to get the value when they need it, but the service isn't initiating the data flow, the consumer is.

Now, in your RoasterService, the trick is to return an observable that first references `countryCode$`, then makes your http call with that data:

```js
export class RoasterService {

    private endPoint: string = SERVER_URL;

    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private helper: HelperService) { }

    getRoasters(page?: number, limit?: number): Observable<Roaster[]> {
        const reqLimit = limit || 15;
        const reqPage = page || 0;

        return this.helper.countryCode$.pipe(
            switchMap(cc => this.httpService.get<Roaster[]>(... use cc in here ...))
        );
    }

}
```

You can see we define the response of the `getRoasters()` method to start with `helpers.countryCode$` then we pipe that result into [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) which will internally subscribes to our http.get() observable (*when getRoasters is subscribed to*) and emits its response.

Comment: To the title of your question, you could use ReplaySubject(1) instead of behavior subject. With behavior subject, it will emit a default value. In your case, this default isn’t meaningful, so best not to emit until you have a “real value”.